# Is a parameterized vector field still a vector field?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vectors, vector-analysis

Suppose I have a vector field from $\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^3$,

$$
\mathbf{A}(\mathbf{x})=A_1(\mathbf{x})\mathbf{\hat{e}}_1+A_2(\mathbf{x})\mathbf{\hat{e}}_2+A_3(\mathbf{x})\mathbf{\hat{e}}_3
$$
where $\mathbf{x}=x_1\mathbf{\hat e}_1+x_2\mathbf{\hat e}_2+x_3\mathbf{\hat e}_3$.

Now suppose $\mathbf{x}$ is a function of, say $l$, $\mathbf{x}(l)=x_1(l)\mathbf{\hat e}_1+x_2(l)\mathbf{\hat e}_2+x_3(l)\mathbf{\hat e}_3$. The vector field is now 
$$
\mathbf{A}(\mathbf{x}(l))=A_1(\mathbf{x}(l))\mathbf{\hat{e}}_1+A_2(\mathbf{x}(l))\mathbf{\hat{e}}_2+A_3(\mathbf{x}(l))\mathbf{\hat{e}}_3
$$

Is this still a vector field $\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$?

If not, what is it called?

Comment: It seems that you are restrictinf the given vector field to the image of the map $l\mapsto \mathbf x(l)$

Comment: If you are setting up to take an integral of the vector field over a curve within $\mathbb R^3,$ you might start this way.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my take on this.

When you say that $\newcommand{A}{{\mathbf A}}\newcommand{x}{{\mathbf x}}
\newcommand{e}{\mathbf{\hat{e}}}
\A(\x)=A_1(\x)\e_1+A_2(\x)\e_2+A_3(\x)\e_3$ is a vector field
$\newcommand{R}{\mathbb{R}}\R^3 \to \R^3,$
you mean that $\A: \R^3\to\R^3$ is the function defined by
$\x \mapsto A_1(\x)\e_1+A_2(\x)\e_2+A_3(\x)\e_3.$
In that definition, $\x$ is a dummy variable; it would be equally valid to say that $\A$ is defined by
${\mathbf y} \mapsto A_1({\mathbf y})\e_1+A_2({\mathbf y})\e_2+A_3({\mathbf y})\e_3$ or
${\mathbf m} \mapsto A_1({\mathbf m})\e_1+A_2({\mathbf m})\e_2+A_3({\mathbf m})\e_3.$

When you later specify that the symbol $\x$ denotes a particular function
$\R\to\R^3$ defined by
$l \mapsto x_1(l)\e_1+x_2(l)\e_2+x_3(l)\e_3,$
you make it awkward to continue to use $\x$ as a dummy variable in the definitions of vector fields. But this does not "undefine" the vector field $\A,$ which can still be described using a different dummy variable.

So $\A$ still exists and is still a vector field $\R^3 \to \R^3.$
But in addition to that, $\x$ is a vector function $\R\to\R^3,$ and so is $\A\circ\x,$ the composition of the field $\A$ with the function $\x$;
that is, $\mathbf F = \A\circ\x$ is a vector function 
$\mathbf F:\R\to\R^3$ defined by $l \mapsto \mathbf F(l) = \A(\x(l)).$